# Differences between Java applet and application graphic capabilities

Tags: java, graphics, applet

Is there anything, talking about graphic capabilities, that a Java application can do, while an applet cannot?
I'm referring to java libraries (like Swing), not to native ones.

edit: I need to create a user interface for graph visualization, probably using the [spring embedder algorithm](http://www.leda-tutorial.org/en/unofficial/ch05s03s08.html)
Initial downloading times are not so important, now I'm focusing mainly on what **2D graphic capabilities** using **Swing** that one application has that an applet hasn't

I think that my graphic interface should look like [Visual Thesaurus](http://www.visualthesaurus.com/)

Comment: Do you care about download times, for example using Java3D would add to the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using an applet, without jumping through major hoops, you won't be able to get access to the lower graphic levels, so you won't be able to use the OpenGL binding libries, such as jogl, which could be a major issue, depending on what you are trying to do.

You will also experience significant download penalties if you use something like Java3D in the applet.

What are you looking at trying to do, that would lead to this question?

Some context would help in you getting better answers.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing regarding graphic capabilities a Java application can do an applet can't.
Unsigned applets have some restrictions, while signed applets can do anything a Java application can.
Read: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

If you are thinking of using JOGL for 3D graphics, read about unsigned applets in http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-1.1.0/jogl-1.1.0-windows-i586/Userguide.html

Answer (score 0):

A Java applet basically uses Swing so the simple answer is; no, not really.

However, if you are writing a Java application (non-applet) you may utilize other GUI libraries than Swing (such as [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)), so in that regard a Java application has greater choices and (potentially) capabilities.